# Is there any alternative to cefsharp in C#? The latest version and cefsharp compiled by me and compiled by others cannot play mp4 video

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I want to play a video file with a browser core that supports winforms. I am using google's cefsharp here. Due to the copyright issue of mp4 files, Google does not provide mp4 playback rights for open source projects. Cefsharp cannot be compressed and packaged together with fody. After packaging, cefsharp cannot run normally and cannot open html files normally.

The cefsharp I am currently using needs to convert files to webm format before they can be played in the program. If too many videos need to be converted, this will cause the CPU and memory to exceed the maximum threshold of the physical device, causing the program to report an error and terminate.

Also is there any way or other control to support html5 and play mp4 video?

If there are other lightweight kernels that support html5 to play mp4 files, I think the program should be compressed from 500mb to tens of mb

I tried to use Firefox's browser kernel, tried to use cefsharp compiled by myself, and cefsharp compiled by others, but the result was that I couldn't play any normal MP4 files without problems.

I want my program to support HTML5, play mp4 files, and play various audio files, but it will not appear bloated, just like the size of my current program of about 500 mb

Comment: I know cefsharp can cause compile/build problems, as getting the correct version for the .net assembly one is using can be difficult.

Comment: Yes, so I wonder is there any other browser core that can replace it to display my local html files. Of course, there must be a local connection of mp4 in this html file

Comment: Have you tried using the Windows Media Player control to play your video in your Winforms form?  Doing all of the things you're describing in Winforms seems like a really big ask.

Comment: No, because my client doesn't want me to do this, because I can directly use the program to call the browser to directly display other content in html and play mp4. I told him and he replied directly that it can't be done that way. He wants to embed the browser kernel or other methods in the developed program to display html5 content and play video directly in the program.

Comment: How about https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/ ..?

Comment: Thank you, webview2 perfectly solved my problem of not being able to play videos.

Comment: How about Xilium.CefGlue?

Comment: Thank you, sir, I have fully realized the functions I need by using the webview recommended by Mr. AKX. It is very light and saves 400mb of space for me

Answer (score 1):

To make my comment an answer you can accept:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/ sounds like it would fit the bill.

Comment: I just used it in my project and it worked. Thanks for the suggestion